# What app is this?

Tags: applications

Does anyone have any idea what app this is? I can't seem to figure it out, since there's no descriptive words on the app's screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. It's called Candid.

[Here](http://www.becandid.com) is the link to the site.